# keyboard shortcut to quit 'telnet'

Tags: windows, telnet

on Windows XP/server 2003

When telnet some remote host on a specified port, after connection established, sometimes press ctrl+] doesn't quit. Is there any command can quit instead of just close the command line window? Thanks.

EDIT:
But sometimes even type <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd>, telnet command line doesn't show up, still stuck at the blank screen.

Answer (score 57):

<kbd>ctrl+]</kbd> is an escape sequence that puts telnet into command mode, it doesn't terminate the session.  If you type `close` after hitting <kbd>ctrl+]</kbd>, that will "close" the telnet session.

Comment: Weird, Ctrl+] doesn't seem to work. Also, why do you type `close` instead of simply typing `q`?

Comment: I think of them as "opening" and "closing" connections rather than "quitting" a session.  If you run telnet by itself with no other options, you would use `open host.domain.com`.  So to me, `close` is `open`'s obvious partner and just makes more sense.  However, `q` also works, and is certainly fewer letters :)

Comment: close takes me to `Microsoft Telnet>` and `q` or `quit` takes me to `C:\Windows\system32>`

Answer (score 18):

on German keyboards the following keystrokes will help

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd>

or rather

<kbd>Strg</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd>

Comment: Very true. On a German keyboard <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> does not (!) work. I'm sure other keyboard layouts need other combinations.

Comment: for swiss german it is CTRL + ¨

Comment: For French, it's CTRL + '$'

Comment: For Slovenian use Ctrl + č

Answer (score 8):

You can use the 'quit' command, or abbreviate it to just 'q' if you like.

Answer (score 3):

The solution worked for me is

```
CTRL $
```

Then after when you will be in telnet invite type

```
quit
```

then enter to exit from telnet and return to your DOS invite

Answer (score 2):

I'm not terribly familiar with Windows telnet, but local behavior on non-Windows boxes using telnet is a combination of the telnet state and that of the terminal or enclosing window and shell.  (If your remote connection has changed the echo mode, font color, interrupt status, and etc, killing telnet has no effect on that local status.)

Does Windows have similar local status?  (I assume so, or most text editors and many other programs wouldn't work in telnet windows.)

For Unix, the typical sequence was <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> → `quit` → <kbd>return</kbd> → `stty sane` → <kbd>return</kbd> to get local control and tty sanity.  What's the Windows equivalent of "tty sane"?

Answer (score 2):

Standard way of disconnecting the line in most applications is <kbd>~</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>, keep in mind, that often this has to be typed in blindly, so press enter a couple of times: <kbd>Enter</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>.

This is also the standard way of closing the connection on an SSH session, that became unresponsive.

Comment: Doesn't work: `Invalid Command. type ?/help for help`

Comment: tilde then dot was used by `rlogin`, and subsequently by `ssh` (at least on Unix); it was not and is not used by `telnet`. (Some programs like `ed`, and some protocols like SMTP and NNTP, use a *line* containing only dot to terminate data.) Most `telnet` clients, including Windows, default to ctrl-] but can be set to something else.

Answer (score 1):

`ctrl+]` will take you to command mode if the telnet client is already connected; from there you can type (q)uit to exit.

If it's connecting, however (or failing to connect...), then there is no way to interrupt the process until it times out.

Answer (score 1):

On a French keyboard I have to use ctrl+$

Then 'quit' from the resulting telnet prompt.

Answer (score 0):

maybe with `ctrl + d` ?

Answer (score 0):

At least in my Linux system, the only way to exit from a telnet session is by using the following keys (pressing the 3 keys together: Ctrl, AltGr,+
and then the following prompt appears: telnet>
Now press the key q 
and the telnet session will be terminated.