# How to exit from telnet in xterm (ctrl+], ctrl+'+', ctrl+d) don't work

Tags: terminal, telnet, xterm

Can't exit from telnet while connected to host.
Commands like (Ctrl+], Ctrl+'+', Ctrl+D) etc. don't work.
I have tried all the suggestions from [keyboard shortcut to quit 'telnet'](https://serverfault.com/questions/175664/keyboard-shortcut-to-quit-telnet).
Are there any other options available?

Comment: I found a new one that worked: Ctrl+5.

Comment: Command `exit`?

Answer (score 0):

I found a new one that worked in my case: `Ctrl`+`5`.